# How to iterate through a list using recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I've got a list like this below and I'm trying to get a list of all subnodes. I need to find all children and subchildren of a list. In this case it should return exact this list.

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    parent: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    parent: 3,
  }
];
```

I'm trying to choose whether or not call the function again in many ways but the result is always wrong.

```
const getNodes = (n) => {
   
  let family = [];
  for (let i of n) {
    const sons = data.filter(x => x.parent === i.id); 
    if (sons.length !== 0) {
      family.push(getNodes(sons));
    } else {
      family.push(i);
    }
  }
  return family;
};

console.log(getNodes([data[0]]));
```

Comment: *"In this case it should..."*: which case? Can you create a runnable snippet (use toolbutton in editor) that has the data initalisation?

Comment: Convert the list to an object of the form `{id1: parent1, id2: parent2, ...}`. Then it's easy to follow all the parent chains.

Comment: @Barmar I can't. This is a example model. In fact when I run data.filter(...) I'm executing a database query.

Comment: I mean you do this transformation to the result of the query.

Comment: In fact I don't have this list. I start with an id and I have to look up all childs and subchilds in the db. Each time I call getNodes I need to run another db query to get the others subnodes.

Comment: Then don't start the question by saying "I have this list".

Comment: Use a query like `SELECT id FROM table WHERE parent IN ?`. Then repeat this using all the IDs returned by this query. Keep doing this until the query returns an empty result.

Answer (score 1):

Let's transform that to a tree.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    parent: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    parent: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    parent: 3,
  }
];

// first obj of nodes grouped by id
var obj_nodes = data.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.id] = { ...item, children: [] };
  return agg;
}, {})
// console.log(obj_nodes)

// connecting edges (child parent relations)
data.forEach(function(item) {
  var source = obj_nodes[item.id];
  var destination = obj_nodes[item.parent];
  
  destination && destination.children.push(source);
}, {})

var trees = Object.values(obj_nodes);

var result = trees[0]
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important}
```

Comment: The might of `reduce` :)